# Retrieve Pandas Rows which Contain Multiple Text Query in Any Order

Tags: pandas, dataframe, mapping, contains

suppose I have this dataframe table with four rows:

```
Text
-----
there is an issue
very enormous issue
the issue is difficult
you think
```

Is there any way in Pandas to retrieve rows which contains "issue" or "is" in any order or maybe mapping function? Therefore, the result should be like this:

```
df[df['Text'].somefunction('issue, is')

Text
-----
there is an issue
very enormous issue
the issue is difficult
```

All three of the rows contain "is" or "issue" in any order. Therefore, you could also write in the function somefunction('is', 'issue') because the exact position is not matter. I tried with Pandas contain but it returns the exact row according to query ('the issue is difficult'). Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
df[df['Text'].str.contains('is|issue')
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html)

Comment: It works, but I have another case: How is it if you want to return a row that must contain both strings in any order? So, the result now will be 1st and 3rd row.

Comment: You would replace the "|" with a "&".

You can read more about [bitwise operators here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).